# [autoad api]create custom entity using .net

Tags: autodesk-forge

1. Is it possible to make a custom entity with only .net(C#)
2. if not, After make custom entity with objectarx, can I use it by .net
3. if than, Can objectarx and its wrapper be used in various cad version in common(one build like .net plugin dll)(ex 2019,2020,2021)?

Comment: auttodesk-forge tag is for the questions of Forge ( web service). It sounds you  are asking pure AutoCAD desktop API questions. The best forum is  https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/net/bd-p/152 . but for your convenience, we will try to help in this post. I have asked a colleague who is expert of AutoCAD to share comments. Short answer in my mind is: yes, only ObjectARX (actually DBX) supports creating custom entity. It is possible to use custom entity in .NET, but may  have some tricks ( please wait for my colleague's response)

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. Yes
3. Yes, provided the Autocad release is binary compatible with previous release, else you may have to recompile with target vc++ compiler.